# Captcha not show on customer registration page

Tags: magento2.2, login-register

[image]CAPTCHA not show on customer register page when submit form invalid CAPTCHA error error i disable it from admin and after clearing cache enable it but nothing error gone.

Comment: Did you use deafult Magento captcha?

Comment: yes from customer configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you set Displaying Mode --> Always

It shows default show in register page

If you set Displaying Mode --> After number of attempts to login

Number of Unsuccessful Attempts to Login --> Set number as per your requirement

Comment: display mode set is "After number of attempts to login" and "Number of Unsuccessful Attempts to Login" set 3

Comment: Is captcha show or not?

Comment: no i try to clear cache as well

Comment: Enable CAPTCHA on Storefront --> Yes ?

Comment: yes enabled and create user is selectedas u can see above in question

Comment: Did you try wrong credentials at 3 times? in registration page

Comment: captcha not show in form when i submit form " Incorrect CAPTCHA " error occur

Comment: Did you try Enable CAPTCHA on Storefront set NO?

Comment: this option remove the captcha from form i try it when i set NO it hide all other options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95416/discussion-between-msa-and-shan-haider).

Answer (score 1):

In Backend

`Stores/Configuration/Customers/Customer Configuration/CAPTCHA`

```
Enable CAPTCHA on Storefront set NO
```

then

```
Stores/Configuration/Security/Google reCaptcha
```

***In General set***

> 1. Google API website key
> 2. Google API secret key

***Frontend***

> Enable --Yes  and select what you want

Comment: already set @savan

Comment: so just clean and flush Magento Cache and also clear browser cache and check again

Comment: captcha not showing still

Comment: @ShanHaider see my updated answer

Comment: i am using magento 2.2.5 this path does not exist Stores/Configuration/Security/Google reCaptcha

Comment: okay then if you want plugin ref => https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/

Comment: thanks for information now i install this extension